# IRbbionx <editBox/> How to pass a reference to the VBA code

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
<editBox id="layout_deck_search_replace_locate_Caption_item"
                        label="Caption Item"
                        showLabel="false"
                        sizeString="xxx"
                        maxLength="3"
                        onChange="layout_search_replace.jump_to_caption_item" />
```

---

[image]

---

```
 Sub jump_to_caption_item(ByVal control As IRibbonControl, ByRef strText)

    selection.collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd


        a = "Figure " & Str(strText)

        MsgBox a
                With selection.Find

                    .Font.Bold = True
                    .Text = "Figure " & Str(strText)

                    .Forward = True
                    .Wrap = wdFindContinue

                    .MatchWildcards = False
                    .Replacement.Text = ""
                    .Execute

                End With End Sub
```

Above is my xml and vba code,
I want to find Figure 1 when i write "1" in editbox

---

When I write "1" in **editbox**, can msgbox "Figure 1", but my word can't go to "Figure 1". because **"Figure " & Str(strText)** is not a string?

Comment: It seems to me that the down-votes were applied with a dash of undue haste. This question has more merit than the way it is put.

Comment: Sorry, my English is not good, may not express clearly, can anyone know my code where there is a problem, provide a point to help I am very grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will find the number in the caption. You may have to tweak it to find the picture under which that number is found.

```
Private Sub GoToFigure(ByVal Num As Integer)
    ' 27 Dec 2017

    Dim Fld As Field

    For Each Fld In ActiveDocument.Fields
        With Fld
            If (.Type = wdFieldSequence) And _
               (InStr(1, .Code, "figure", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
                If .Result = Num Then
                    .Select
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next Fld
End Sub
```

The Sub's parameter `Num` is the number of the caption you want to find. Call the sub with code like this.

```
GoToFigure 1
```

where "1" is the number from your EditBox.

Comment: thanks, I changed `Str(strText)` to `CInt(strText)` is access to do

Comment: I'm glad I could help you, kerry. Please mark my answer as "Selected". Thank you.